# "Alcohol intoxication" naming confusion

Tags: food-chemistry, alcohols, toxicity

From Wikipedia: "Alcohol intoxication is the result of alcohol entering the bloodstream faster than it can be metabolized by the liver, which breaks down the ethanol into non-intoxicating byproducts."
Why is it called **intoxication** if ethanol is broken down to **non-intoxicating** byproducts? This is so confusing.

Comment: Read that sentence again. Intoxication occurs when the liver, which is responsible for detoxification, *cannot* keep up with the alcohol intake.

Comment: @orthocresol I think the reason I don't understand that is I don't know what intoxication really means chemically. Can you explain this a little, to a person who only have basic chemistry knowledge?

Comment: If that's your question, vote to migrate to biology.SE.

Answer (score 3):

You're losing the forest in the trees. Ethanol is intoxicating. The metabolized by-products are not.

Note:

> "Alcohol intoxication is the result of alcohol entering the bloodstream faster than it can be metabolized by the liver..."

Alcohol can only be removed from the body my metabolism of the liver. This phrase is just stating that if you intake alcohol faster than your liver can destroy it, then the level of alcohol in your blood is rising.

Now the other half:

> "...which breaks down the ethanol **into** non-intoxicating byproducts."

The by-products that the liver made ethanol into are not intoxicating thus only the ethanol contributes to your intoxication.